# Filtering Data in SharePoint Library from InfoPath Repeating Table/Sections

Tags: infopath, form, form-library

I'm pretty new to SharePoint and Infopath, and I am working on training attendance forms, and I'd like to be able to store these forms in a library and filter the completed forms by who attended and what procedures were the topic. I have a repeating table for attendees, but it does not export to SharePoint in a manner of which I can filter.

I can get all the information into the column, but it comes in as a single string instead of individual values. I'd like to do the same with the Procedures, which is a repeating section but can live with making a new form for each trained procedure for the time being.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks! I'm using SharePoint Online and Infopath 2013. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make a SharePoint list with the meta content you want to use and use that to create your form  Make a connection to that list in InfoPath to use those columns as your fields in your form.  Then, for each one of the InfoPath forms created, you will have a row of the data entered into the form on the list for which you can do what you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm able to connect to a SharePoint form library and list, the problem occurs when I try to sort by the information in a repeating table. For this form, I'd like to be able to add a varying amount of trainees, then filter the list by anyone who attended.

Comment: You could create you a rule in your InfoPath that would trigger a flag on your list/library your could filter off of.  That would require someone to input into the form that the person did attend, but it is an idea.  You can hide this in the background.  You can use a secondary list for this to capture who signed up and populate your meta data for those who attended, or anyother information you want to see, out side of your form list.  Populate it with a workflow after the initial form creation.

Comment: Hm seems intriguing. How would I go about doing something like this?